# In a SMS, can there be a link that opens the dialpad with a particular number ? How to do it?

Tags: php

For our business we have created websites with a CTA that opens the dialpad on clicking a button.

Like a web page has a click to call function that opens a dialpad, We want to do sms marketing that will have a URL, on clicking which it will open a dialpad with the number fed to call.

I have tried re-direction of a page, but however the feature doesnt work without click action.

Anyone has tried it or can you suggest how do I get this done ?